# ordenar datos de json en javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

quiero ordenar la data de un JSON que obtengo de una API, agrupar los Post por usuario, es decir userId=1 obtener todos sus post, la informacion que me da es las publicaciones hechas por los usuarios  con id, titulo, su cuerpo y el userID, quisiera ordenar por usuario este es el codigo que estoy haciendo .

```
let dataByUser = [];
 const sortByUser =data.map((data,indexs) => {
    //console.log(indexs+" "+data.body+" "+data.id +" "+data.title );
    dataByUser[data.userId] = [];
    dataByUser[data.userId][indexs] = ({body : data.body,
                                          id: data.id,
                                          title: data.title});
  return dataByUser;
 });
 console.log(sortByUser);
```

Pero eso esto es lo que obtengo por consola:

> (100) [Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11)]
>   0
>   :
>   Array(11)
>   1
>   :
>   (10) [empty × 9, {…}]
>   2
>   :
>   (20) [empty × 19, {…}]
>   3
>   :
>   (30) [empty × 29, {…}]
>   4
>   :
>   (40) [empty × 39, {…}]
>   5
>   :
>   (50) [empty × 49, {…}]
>   6
>   :
>   (60) [empty × 59, {…}]
>   7
>   :
>   (70) [empty × 69, {…}]
>   8
>   :
>   (80) [empty × 79, {…}]
>   9
>   :
>   (90) [empty × 89, {…}]
>   10
>   :
>   (100) [empty × 99, {…}]
>   length
>   :
>   11
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Array(0)

Este es la estructura que obtengo [json](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de cómo es el JSON original para poder ayudarte mejor. Para ello puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/189746/edit) y agregarlo. Gracias.

Comment: Creo que no entiendes el funcionamiento del método [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map), estás creando un array que tiene N veces el mismo array, que resulta ser tu array ordenado. ¿Por qué no usar [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)?

Comment: Si cierto estoy creando un array de un array, fue mis lapsus brutus . lo que quiero es agrupar por userId . es decir por ejemplo en sortByUser[1] tengo todos los post del usuario de id 1

Comment: por favor añade un ejemplo, de tu json, de otro modo solo tu sabes que estructura tiene

Comment: Listo ya coloque un enlace al final del post con la estructura

Comment: Jorge; tengo el mismo problema, ¿ como te quedo el código finalmente?

Comment: Lo solucione cambiando dataByUser[data.userId][indexs] por dataByUser[data.userId].push() , porque de la primera formaera como escribir en la misma posicion y se guardaba el ultimo nada mas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se muy bien que estás buscando, pero te dejo una manera de ordenarlos (está comentada en el código porque no es necesario si los vamos a agrupar) y una manera de agruparlos de manera de acceder con el `userId`. Para listar todos los posts del userId 1: `byUser[1]`. Para listar todos los post del idUser 2: `byUser[2]`... y así sucesivamente.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {

    var dataByUser = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);


    /* dataByUser = dataByUser.sort((a, b) => {
    
      if (a.userId == b.userId) {
        return 0;
      }
      if (a.userId < b.userId) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.userId > b.userId) {
        return -1;
      }
    
    }) */

    var byUser = {};

    dataByUser.map(o => {
      if (o.userId in byUser) {
        byUser[o.userId].push(o);
      } else {
        byUser[o.userId] = [];
        byUser[o.userId].push(o);
      }
    })

    //console.log("----TODOS----")
    //console.log(byUser)
    console.log("----Todos los POST del id 1----")
    console.log(byUser[1])
    

  }
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Gracias acaba de hacer un codigo parecido ya que como lo estaba haciendo me creaba muchos slotEmpty pero bueno ya resolvi con  este codigo: let dataByUser = [];
  
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       if (!(data[i].userId in dataByUser)) {
           dataByUser[data[i].userId] = [];
       }
       dataByUser[data[i].userId].push({body : data[i].body,
                                             id: data[i].id,
                                           title: data[i].title});

     }
     console.log(dataByUser);